# sync one of my git repo branches with another branch in another project

Tags: git, github

I am building project A which uses code from Project B.
each project is on different repositories.
what I want is to clone the "Main" branch in project B then make a branch "Base" on project A.
if some issues got solved in branch "Main" in project B I want to be able to pull it in "Base" in project A.
I want to keep two branches in different repositories in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but it might cause some collisions if the two projects happen to share unrelated files under the same paths.

First, add project B as a remote in project A:

```sh
git remote add projectB git@github.com:example/projectB.git
git fetch projectB
```

Then, set the upstream branch of "Base" in project A to branch "Main" from project B, like so:

```sh
git branch --set-upstream-to=projectB/Main Base
```

Whenever you `git pull` when working on branch `Base`, git will pull in changes from branch Main in projectB.

Instead of this approach, consider [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: well I have empty  projectA, I run command these commands in order  `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/projectA.git`,`git checkout -b Base`, then I run your 3 commands after `git branch --set-upstream-to=projectB/Main Base` I get this message  "branch 'base' does not exist".

Comment: so I used `git merge projectB/Main --allow-unrelated-histories` after adding empty file then pushed it to projectA/Base